# how to add rel=nofollow to some specific external links in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, seo, nofollow

The small banners loaded on the site of the page does not have the rel="nofollow" attribute - and we would like this to be added.

http://poltr.com/?s=dans&post_type=aktivitet is the link, you can see the sidebar banners, they are curently set to:

just an example:

```
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'koebenhavn', 'click', 'DYNAMIC URL' );" href="DYNAMIC URL"><img alt="" src="DYNAMIC IMG PATH"></a>
```

I want them to be changed to:

```
<a rel="nofollow" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'koebenhavn', 'click', 'DYNAMIC URL' );" href="DYNAMIC URL"><img alt="" src="DYNAMIC IMG PATH"></a>
```

Basically I want to add **rel="nofollow" to links of sidebar banners only.**

Also i don't want to use Plugin.

Comment: use `$(object).attr("rel","nofollow");`

Comment: That's realtively simple to add attribute to specific anchors inside container but you didn't provided any relevant HTML markup regarding the banner container and anyway, this should be done server side, before rendering HTML

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, As it have to done at server side as it has to done in wordpress.

Comment: I am learning wordpress and it's functions, can you please guide where it will be added.

Comment: you need to find the sidebar template in theme directory and add the attribute

Comment: i didn't have an idea where to add this attribute and where to find sidebar template in directory, that is why I came to experts so they can help me. I only have access to website through FTP.

Comment: At some point someone will have to write some code to fix this. If you can't then contact your them e support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by simple javascript code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('body > a').attr('rel','nofollow')
    });
```

Add this to your footer.php file this will add attribute to all tags.

Or can be done by using ID's for particular `a` tags

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('body > a#ID_OF_A_TAG').attr('rel','nofollow')
    });
```

Hope this will do

Comment: hi @parkash Rao , i added this in footer.php like this: <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body > a#banner_left_lille').attr('rel','nofollow')
    });
 </script>

Comment: Hi @blunor, try this `<script> $(document).ready(function() { $('a#MY_ID').attr('rel','nofollow'); }); </script>` and make sure you have pasted correct ID of `<a id="MY_ID">`tag.  **MY_ID** in this case...